# nodejs passportjs-twitter connect ETIMEDOUT

Tags: node.js, twitter

I am using [nodejs](/questions/tagged/nodejs) and *[passportjs-twitter](http://passportjs.org/guide/twitter/)* to make the twitter authentication into my website,but when I start the process,I always get the error as below:

**Error: connect ETIMEDOUT at Strategy.OAuthStrategy._createOAuthError**

I read the *[passportjs-twitter](http://passportjs.org/guide/twitter/)* for many times and read many examples on the Internet,I found they are coded in the same style as what I do in my code and I don't know the reason of it,but I am always got the error,
can anyone help me to analysis it?Below are the relevant code block:

```js
var twitter_consumerKey='******',
var twitter_consumerSecret='*************',
var twitter_callbackURL='http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/twitter/callback',

app.get('/auth/twitter',site.logInTwitter);
app.get('/auth/twitter/callback',site.logInTwitterCallback);

var passport=require('passport');
var TwitterStrategy = require('passport-twitter').Strategy;

exports.logInTwitter=passport.authenticate('twitter');

exports.logInFacebook=passport.authenticate('facebook');


exports.logInTwitterCallback=function(req,res,next){
   passport.authenticate('twitter',function(err,info){
      if(err){
         //return next(err);
         console.log("===========ifeng====================",err);
         return res.render("templates/logInPage",info);
      }
      return res.render("templates/logInPage",info)
   })(req,res.next);
}


   passport.use(new TwitterStrategy({
   consumerKey:twitter_consumerKey,
   consumerSecret:twitter_consumerSecret,
   callbackURL:twitter_callbackURL
},function(token,tokenSecret,profile,done){
   console.log("======token:\t",token);
   //console.log(profile);
   return done(null,null);
}));

passport.serializeUser(function(user,done){
   done(null,user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(user,done){
   done(null,user);
});
```

**Now when I start the authentication process I alway got the error stack as below,I can not even get the twitter login page,can anyone help me to analysis it,thanks in advance!**

```js
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
   at Strategy.OAuthStrategy._createOAuthError (D:\code\nodejsWorkspace\andy\node_modules\passport-twitter\node_modules\passport-oauth1\lib\strategy.js:352:17)
   at D:\code\nodejsWorkspace\andy\node_modules\passport-twitter\node_modules\passport-oauth1\lib\strategy.js:218:41
   at D:\code\nodejsWorkspace\andy\node_modules\passport-twitter\node_modules\passport-oauth1\node_modules\oauth\lib\oauth.js:543:17
   at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (D:\code\nodejsWorkspace\andy\node_modules\passport-twitter\node_modules\passport-oauth1\node_modules\oauth\lib\oauth.js:421:9)
   at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:95:17)
   at CleartextStream.socketErrorListener (http.js:1547:9)
   at CleartextStream.emit (events.js:95:17)
   at Socket.onerror (tls.js:1440:17)
   at Socket.emit (events.js:117:20)
   at net.js:440:14
```

Comment: Yeah we all love China